# Kill navigation bar in KitKat

Tags: android

I was using this code to hide the navigation bar. It works fine on older versions of android, but on KitKat doesnt work.

```
public void KillStatusBar() {

    Process proc = null;

    String ProcID = "79"; // HONEYCOMB AND OLDER

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        ProcID = "42"; // ICS AND NEWER
    }
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2){
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you really "killing" it? You should follow the guidelines:

http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Android 4.0 and lower:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

4.1 and higher:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Yes i am totally disabling it.